# Selected options in Select2 are outside of input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I am new to Select2.

When I have multiple selections Select2 makes a horizontal stretch of the container box.
This is OK till a certain width. But if I select many options the container box gets outside the window.
I tried to set the width with options, but it doesn't have the desired effect.

```
$(".select2").select2({ width: '300' });
```

I did some search and found this solution:

```
.select2-container {    
    max-width:100%;
}
```

This stops the container box from stretching outside the screen, but it doesn't stop the selected options to get bigger than the container box.

[image]

I'm working with bootstrap3.

I need Select2 to do a linebreak once the maximum width is reached and stretch the container box vertically. How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What version of select2 are you using? It should automatically move to a newline out of the box. Maybe there is some sort of conflict with your CSS.